# Hover over toggle menu to display hidden picture

Tags: css, wordpress

I was wondering if it is possible to : when hovering over a toggle menu (has ID 9) in Wordpress to display an hidden image (Lets say has ID 10). It looks like this now https://wortelboeryachting.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Screenshot-2020-04-29-at-20.29.36.png. I want to be able to hover over the toggle menu on the left and make an image, currently hidden behind image on the right, to appear. If possible in CSS addition code because I am not very familiar with JavaScript. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: A good way to post a question is to add Current Progress with code, Desired Output and Actual Output.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use CSS, you can put the images into pseudo-elements of the menu items. Only to show you the concept:

```
.myMenuItems::after {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url('yourimagepath');
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0;
}

#myMenuItem:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Of course you can use a class and it may better to position the image absolute.

If you want to overlay as you said, you can make this happen with the css property "z-index", instead of "opacity".